# How to call a function after an ajax page is completely loaded?

Tags: ajax, function

Using jQuery, I loaded an `enrollment_forms.php` page into a div called `container_level2`. When the `enrollment_forms.php` page is loaded in this `container_level2` I want to call another function.

How can I do this using one function with parameters?

Here is a function I've made:

```
function view_update_load_form(list_index, student_id){
     $.ajax({
            url: "enrollment_forms.php",
            success: function(result){
                $('#container_level2').html(result);
            },
            complete: function(){
                load_form(list_index, student_id);
            }
            }); 
}
```

In the above code I call function with two parameters:

```
view_update_load_form(list_index, student_id)
```

This function loads a page:

```
enrollment_forms.php.
```

when `enrollment.forms.php` is loaded, I want to call second function:

```
load_form(list_index, student_id)
```

with same paramters.

How can I? This doesn't work.
It often calls 2nd function even if page is not completely loaded.

Comment: If i add one alert().. then this works as i need.. :(

Comment: the guy I worked for on these scripts passed away last week.  :( He was by beloved boss. ALLAH may her soul rest in peace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put the `load_form` call inside your `success` function:

```
success: function(result){
    $('#container_level2').html(result);
    load_form(list_index, student_id);
},
```

That way it won't be called before inserting the html.

Comment: no this is not working.... the function i made or as you suggest.. it would work untill i add alert() in this.. on any place..

Comment: Can you elaborate? Do you get a javascript error? Where are you adding the alert()?

Comment: before "load_form"... actually i don't get any err.. rather.. nothing.. if there could be any err.. that could be helpful... :(

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
ajaxComplete();
```

Please refer the following link for more information
[JQuery ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)